Firebase admin authentication works in interpreter but fails in production
I'm interfacing with the resources of a firebase project.
From a VM in GCP I am using python to get information from the database and files from the bucket. The VM has gcloud installed and the VM is authenticated using the firebase service account which should have all privileges for the firebase app.
The VM is a plain generic E2-medium, default networks, default settings.
When I ssh to the VM I use
gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT] --key-file=KEY_FILE 
so that the machine has credentials. These credentials are picked up by any SDK that is to be used. This allows me to read any GCP API using any programming language. I use python. Python can be ran from a file, or one can open an interpreter and type code.
My main problem is that when I use the interpreter everything works, but when I call a function within a server (django/celery/redis) I get an error related to permissions. The code is the following. The exact code works in the interpreter but not in the service.
code:
import firebase_admin
from   firebase_admin import auth, credentials, firestore
from   google.cloud import storage

PROJECT_ID="myprojectid"
BUCKET_NAME="mybucket"

cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'projectId': PROJECT_ID})

storage_client = storage.Client()
db = firestore.client()
            
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

docs = list(
     db.collection(u'mycollection')
     .where(....)
     .stream()
)

As soon as I run this as part of a server in the VM I get the error
[reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "firestore.googleapis.com"
}
metadata {
  key: "method"
  value: "google.firestore.v1.Firestore.RunQuery"
}

However, if I open an interpreter and type the exact same code it works perfectly.
I know I can change the scope in the VM settings, but then why does it work when in the python interpreter? I can even upload files to the bucket.

It sounds like your VM isn't configured correctly.  The mere presence of gcloud isn't going to help you at all when using the Firebase Admin SDK.  You need to set up an environment variable so your code can get a hold of a service account to initialize the SDK (or find some other way to load the credentials to pass to initialize_app).  See the documentation.

It's not just the presence of gcloud, I am authenticated with gcloud and have a config, without it I can't even access the resouces, after authentication with gcloud I can access. This also happens even if I would do cred=credentials.Certificate(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]) or storage.Client.from_service_account_json(os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"])

Your question should probably contain enough information about how you set up your VM (all the steps you take) so that someone can take that and duplicate exactly what you've done to observe the same result.  As it stands right now, the reader of this question has to guess what you've actually done.
